# cut out part of a point cloud

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension, point-clouds

I have an intel D415 depth camera and want to identify obstacles in the path of my robot.
I want to reduce the points from the cam pc=(102720,3) to only a rectangular area where the robot has to pass through

I came up with this list comprehension, p[0] is the x-axis, p[2] the distance and the values are in meters, the robot needs around a 1 meter "door" and I limit the distance to 2 meters.

`inPathPoints = np.asarray([p for p in pc if p[0] > -0.5 and p[0] < 0.5 and p[2] > 0.2 and p[2] < 2])`

On my laptop cProfile shows a runtime of 0.25 seconds for this evaluation.

As the robot needs to check for obstacles while moving I wanted to repeat this check about 5..10 times a 
second. Any hints what I could try to speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of list comprehension, is used `numpy` and came up with this statement:

`inPathPoints = pc[(pc[:, 0] > -0.5) & (pc[:, 0] < 0.5) & (pc[:, 2] > 0.2) & (pc[:, 2] < 2)]`

This is so fast it does not even show up in the profile output.

Comment: Is this an answer to your question? It doesn't look like it to me. You should [edit] your question and add the text of this answer.